# How do I get all radio buttons and their textbox values?

Tags: php, jquery

**Description: On the form appears radio buttons with textboxes. Their count = count that you entered in textbox. In test.php file I need get all radio buttons and their textbox values, it does not matter - checked, unchecked radio buttons state.**

Error is that I get only the most recent values of radiobutton and textbox. I do not see values of previous radiobuttons and textboxes.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function getnewElementID()
{
    var elementID = 0;
    if($(".form-element").length > 0)
        elementID = $(".form-element").length;
    return elementID;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ok1').click(function () {
    var n = $('#box1').val();
    var index = 0;
    var newElementID = getnewElementID();

    if($(".RadioDiv").length > 0)
    index = $(".RadioDiv").length;

    var newElement = "<div class='RadioDiv form-element'><input type='hidden' name='RadioElements["+newElementID+"]' value='radiogroup'/>\n<input  type='text' size='50' name='RadioElementsQueations["+newElementID+"]'  placeholder='question...' >";

        for (var i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            newElement+="<ol><input type='radio' name='RadioElementsValues["+newElementID+"]' value='radio_"+index+"' for='RadioElementsValuesText["+newElementID+"]'>\n\<input type='text' id='radtext' name='RadioElementsValuesText["+newElementID+"]'  size='30' value='choice.."+index+"' ></ol>";
        index++;
        }

    newElement+="</div>";
    $("#myForm").append(newElement);
});});


 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function () {

         var data = $("#myForm").serialize();   

         if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == "0") {    
              alert("Select any value");     
         } else {                       
                $.post ( 
                    "test.php", 
                     data,
                     function (response) {
                     $('#message').html(response);
                     }
                );
        }
        return false;           
        });
});

</script>

</head>
<body> 
    <form id ="myForm" action="test.php">
        <label>Select your favourite Activities:</label><br/>
        <input type="button" name="ok" value="ok" id="ok1">
        <input type="text" value="" id="box1" name="count" size="1"><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit"/> <br/>
    </form>
<div id="message"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php 
    var_dump($_POST); 

    $elements = $_POST['RadioElementsValuesText'];
    if(is_array($elements));
     for ($index = 0; $index<sizeof($elements);$index++)
     {
        $astring = implode("<br/>", $elements);
        echo "Choices: ". $astring."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use checkboxes instead of radio button.
In a post request, only one radio button value will be send for the group name (here 'RadioElementsValuesText').

Use javascript to reproduce the radio button behavior on your checkboxes (only one checked at a time).